# How to update remote files, with updated files with changed name?

Tags: bitbucket

my files (inside a folder) in remote have been updated by merging from some branch.

In my local project(which I had cloned from remote before merging clone with other branch), I have same set of files in same folder. I have changed codes inside of files, added one file, ALSO have changed names of almost all files.

I want to replace remote files with my local files (no need to merge, since these are complete).

I tried by committing and pushing to remote from my local. It tells me to update project. When I update, it replaces my folder with remote folder.

Please suggest, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you change your file name, and make changes to that file, Git will treat this as new file.

Please handle it, as if you have deleted some files and added new files.
Or you should not change the file names before pushing.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I solved it by not changing file names before pushing.